# JavaScript function to return "n" shades of a given color from (dark to light)

Tags: javascript, graphics, colors, rgb

I would like to get the color range of the specific color for generating tag cloud.

Say that user has entered some color with `RGB/HHHHHH` values then I would like to write a function `f(color, no)` which returns `RGB/HHHHHH` for "no" of different shades from dark to light colors for specified "color". These colors then will be useful to display the different tags with different color of same shade. But I would like to avoid black and white shades in it.

Following is example of `F({R:0, G:0, B:255}, 7)` which returns `7` shades of blue.

[image: f({R:0, G:0, B:255}, 7) returns 7 shades of blue]

I would not like it to be true for any RGB combination say for example `(25, 150,150)` also.

Is this function possible using JavaScript or is there any formula for RGB with which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
function generate()
{
  var r = document.querySelector("#R").value%256;
  var g = document.querySelector("#G").value%256;
  var b = document.querySelector("#B").value%256;
  var str="";
  for(var i=0;i<7;i++)
  {
    r+=33;
    g+=33;
    b+=33;
    str+="<div class='swatch' style='background-color:rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")'></div>";
  }
  document.querySelector("#op").innerHTML = str;
  console.log(str);
}
```

```css
.swatch{width:50px;height:25px;margin:1px}
```

```html
<div>R<input type="text" id="R"/></div>
<div>G<input type="text" id="G"/></div>
<div>B<input type="text" id="B"/></div>
<input type="button" onclick="generate()" value="Generate"/>
<div id="op">Generated Color shades</div>
```

Do you want something like this on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oqaza4/2/)? This is a demo that I have built using jQuery.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: @AndrewMyers Done

Answer (score 0):

You want to operate on saturation and value, convert rgb to hsv first and then it is very easy.

Code: http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript

Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV