# What is the Safe HTML color code of Red color from mild RED to very RED? (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a chess program in which it will show a little red for little weak move & darker red for very weak move.

I need 5 level of Red color code from mild to very red.

```
#ff0000
```

is the one, then can you suggest me some.

**Note**: it must be working in all browsers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a color not programming

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324359/javascript-function-to-return-n-shades-of-a-given-color-from-dark-to-light

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go through the alphabet (up to `f`) and you can also used numbers (up to `9`).
eg.

```
Letters:

#aa0000
#bb0000
#cc0000
#dd0000
#ee0000
#ff0000

Numbers:

#990000
#880000
#770000
#660000
#550000
#440000
#330000
#220000
#110000
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hxa4/2/)

It works like `rgb`, which is `red`, `green` and `blue`.

In  `rgb` format, you can only use numbers which can go from `0` to `255`.

(In computers, the component values are often stored as integer numbers in the range 0 to 255, the range that a single 8-bit byte can offer)

```
rgb(red, green, blue);
#    ff    00     00
     ^      ^      ^
  full red 0 green 0 blue
  (255)
```

If the first two are the same, you can also shorten it:

```
#f00
#c00
#900
```

Comment: Instantly minus, why is this? I understand I answered a question that is not 'on-topic' but that doesn't make the answer any less legitimate?

Comment: Don't know.  It looks like a sensible answer to me, and it even squares with the safe chart another user linked.  I'm upvoting.

Comment: My guess is that web-safe colors aren't necessarily 0-9a-f; they are stepped by every three (so 0, 3, 6, 9, c, and f are considered web-safe). That being said, in new development, that particular "web-safe"  rule is outdated.

Comment: what is the difference between letter and number?

Comment: also r u sure it will work in all browser?

Comment: @Tum - Basically, the color codes are given in hexadecimal form. Instead of being base 10 (1-10), the color format is base 16 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f, 10).

Comment: This works in all browsers @Tum and in the most 'simple' terms, it basically changes the 'darkness' of the colour.

Comment: good answer, but darkness is another concept, and even pure red itself converts to a dark color via NTSC's (0.29R)...

Answer (score 1):

you're propably talking about the hex-color-codes which are built by 2 (hexadecimal)digits for red, 2 for green and 2 for blue.

so if you want red colors, you just take the red -> you'll get from 000000 to ff0000.

the first digit is the more important one and the second digit is just detail which you won't need therefore you might just try using 0, or 8 as the second digit and for the first digit you can try every digit(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f)

therefor try 000000, 080000, 100000, 180000, 200000, 280000, and so on